# Asterisk configure error due to missing uuid development package

Tags: linux, installation, asterisk

I am installing asterisk 13.

- OS: Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
- Asterisk version :  asterisk-certified-13.21

While running configure command I am having following error:

```
...
checking for LIBEDIT... no
checking for history_init in -ledit... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... yes
checking for uuid_generate_random in -luuid... no
checking for uuid_generate_random in -le2fs-uuid... no
checking for uuid_generate_random... no
configure: error: *** uuid support not found (this typically means the uuid development package is missing)
...
```

Error indicates that uuid development package is missing 
but i have installed uuid.devel package
Kindly find the out put of the command as follows

```
command :rpm -qa | grep uuid
output:
uuid-1.6.2-26.el7.x86_64
uuid-devel-1.6.2-26.el7.i686
libuuid-2.23.2-21.el7.x86_64
uuid-1.6.2-26.el7.i686
```

Hence i believe i have the required package but still i am having this error any ideas for the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also need the `libuuid-devel` package installed!

Comment: Thank you so much that resolved the earlier issue now there is error for JASON support, i will search existing threads for the same, thanks again for the help.

Comment: That would be `jansson-devel`

Comment: In my case - Centos 8 `jansson-devel` was already installed but was still getting the error.

Answer (score 11):

The question is already answered, but if you came here and you are trying to install **Asterisk on Ubuntu**, try:

```
sudo apt install uuid-dev
```